# Importing projected GeoTIFF and transforming to latitude and longitude coordinates in R

Tags: r, maps, raster

While I am not new to R, I am new to visualizing spatial data in it rather than ArcGIS.

I am attempting to import a GeoTIFF image from a public-access GIS website that is already projected in Mercator (image can be found [here](http://woodshole.er.usgs.gov/pubs/ds-99/webpages/massbay.html#multi)). Using the `raster` package in `R`, I can successfully import the GeoTIFF into R and plot it (see below).

```
> library(raster)
> mb <- raster("/Maps/mb_srelief10m/mb_srelief10m.tif")
> mb
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 8060, 7220, 58193200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : -48598.54, 23601.46, 3850014, 3930614  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=-70.31666666666668 +lat_ts=41.65 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\Connor\Documents\ArcGIS\Maps\mb_srelief10m\mb_srelief10m.tif 
names       : mb_srelief10m 
values      : 0, 255  (min, max)
attributes  :
       ID    COUNT BinValues Value
 from:  0  1460797         0     0
 to  : 51 14795988       255   255
```

[image: Bathymetric profile of Massachusetts Bay]

As you can see, the x- and y-axis labels represent the NAD83 values from the raster file (red boxes in image). Yet, when I attempt to use the `crop` function to use only a portion of this raster file, I cannot select the appropriate area because my user-defined `extent` object is in latitude and longitude coordinates. I understand I can use the `drawExtent` function to manually select the area but I want to automate this process.

My question is:

**How do I transform the raster file so that my axes are in latitude and longitude and I can crop the file using latitude and longitude coordinates?**

If this post would be more appropriate elsewhere, please let me know and I will remove the file. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `projectRaster()`. And I would recommend you to use another name than `raster` for your `RasterLayer`.

Comment: More like projectExtent, you only need to transform the query window. Also don't call your raster that :). Try qr <- raster(extent(...), crs = "+proj=longlat"); projectExtent(qr, projection(yourraster))

Comment: @mdsumner, I followed your advice and created another RasterLayer with projectExtent. The object's dimensions and resolution have been greatly reduced and plot poorly. In addition, my axes are still not in lat-long format

Comment: why reproject the huge raster to the small ROI? Can't you use the raster projection in your project? I'd suggest you to crop it to a larger ROI and then reproject it.

Comment: @PauloCardoso, I am having a difficult time understanding your comment. Could you suggest any material online that would be helpful so I don't take up your time? Thank you